# How can I query the number of album in gallery

Tags: android

In android 2.1 sdk, how can I query the number and the name of each album in the gallery?
And is there an way to launch an intent to allow user to see all pictures of a particular album in the gallery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this yourself you can call:

[getExternalStorageDirectory();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

This will return you the SD Card directory that is used in the Gallery. This is a file, an iterative search of this File using [listFiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) and [isDirectory();](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) will get you the list of albums you want.

An example of an interative file/folder finder is here: (overkill)

[Iterative FileSearch](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet4167.htm)